# Several Direct3D devices and Intel GMA945

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-xp, directx, direct3d

I have created 16 Direct3D devices with size approximately 320x200 pixels. I invoke IDirect3DDevice9::Present for each device in a separate thread every 40 ms. On laptops with Windows XP and integrated Intel GMA945 graphics part of devices is not updated if system tooltip or Start menu are shown. IDirect3DDevice9::Present doesn't return any error codes at that moment, in program everything looks fine, but user can see that move on several of devices freezes. What could be a reason for that?

This works fine on Windows 7 with the same hardware and on Windows XP with different hardware, so the problem only with this combination. I should support this since my customers are use this combination of the hardware and OS. MSDN says nothing about that I should create only one D3D device (at least I can't find it) so problem should be elsewhere.

What I'm trying to find is that possibly there's some combination of flags that could solve my problem. At the moment I use the following:

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS param = {};
param.Windowed = TRUE;    
param.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;   
param.hDeviceWindow = GetSafeHwnd();
param.BackBufferCount = 1;
param.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
param.BackBufferWidth = m_szDevice.Width;
param.BackBufferHeight = m_szDevice.Height;
param.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE;
param.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_VIDEO;
param.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
param.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
param.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've distributed DirectX software for a couple of years and along the way learnt that Intel graphics chipsets have incredibly crap drivers.  Once I even saw a driver revision that couldn't render a quad properly.  So when you have a problem with an Intel chipset, if you're on the latest driver version, you pretty much have to accept your solution is going to be "start shotgun hacking things until it works".

Sorry to give you a lame answer, but Intel chipsets are not well engineered at all.  They're solely there to get something - anything - on the screen, probably for office worker type use.  Beyond "does it do aero glass" Intel probably don't give a hoot what it does or how well it works.  An alternative "solution" is to distribute your application anyway, state that Intel chipsets are not supported due to glitches in the hardware/driver support, and contact Intel and see if you can get a fix from them.

And people say OpenGL has bad drivers...

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. The device is supposed to map basically 1-to-1 to a GPU. Create one device, and use it to draw to 16 different windows, in whichever way works for you. (Multiple swap chains is the usual approach, afaik)

Creating 16 devices and trying to get them to render in parallel is just *asking* for trouble.
D3D is designed around the assumption that only one device will be doing serious rendering at any time.

In theory, the difference should only be a matter of performance, but in your case, trying to run 16 devices in parallel on a crappy Intel GPU, it wouldn't surprise me if it causes rendering errors  such as you'er seeing.

Comment: This actually doesn't work only on one combination of OS and hardware, so why I shouldn't do that? MSDN says nothing against it. Using 16 separate devices makes architecture of my project more clear. I can't change it without heavy refactoring.

Comment: @Kirill: I can't find it right now, but MSDN *does* say something against it (that's where I learned it). But as always with MSDN, you have to know where to look. I'll see if I can find it later, when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you say "doesn't return any error codes at that moment", are you running the D3D9 debug version at max debugging level?

Second, everytime you create a new device and it gains focus, the surfaces of all the existing devices are lost. Are you calling reset on *all* of them after creation?

Other than that, it's like the other answers state: don't create many devices from a single application. Device creation might start throwing errors after 9 or 10 devices, you are really pushing it with 16. Use a single device with multiple swap chains in stead, see for instance this [DirectX 8](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/rendering_to_multiple_windows.htm) tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I've tested with debug version. And why I shouldn't create 16 devices, MSDN says nothing agains it.

Comment: @Kirill: you shouldn't do it because you're getting errors, and even if you weren't, it'd only be a matter of time before you came across a GPU or driver which failed to handle 16 devices. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Intel graphics chips, particularly the integrated GMA ones, have never been known for their capabilities. They can report caps they don't have and later fail, with or without errors codes (had bug reports of this, supposedly supported shader models later failed to compile). It is possible that you're running into a similar problem with their chips/drivers. Does it work on other hardware or with different drivers?

I assume, from having multiple devices, they are windowed? Have you checked the window handles, or tried explicitly passing the handle/viewport when presenting? Do any of the devices get reset?

It is possible the display drivers are not properly repainting the window after the tooltip or start menu are shown (more likely if its a window under the tooltip/menu). Have you checked the window for focus, made sure it gets painted, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by checking window handles?

Comment: The `HWND` used in the device or present parameters. Although, as the others mentioned, 16 devices isn't a great idea.